# Old stereo with a blown fuse

Tags: fuses

I have an elderly but much loved Kenwood cd/radio/tape stack that has blown a fuse. The fuse rating is T800mAL 250volt. For reasons beyond me these don't seem to be available in the UK and the Amazon US supplier does not ship to UK either. Could someone tell me, please, if there is a compatible fuse that I can install.

Comment: What is the reason you think the fuse has blown?

Comment: The wire is broken. I checked the other 3 fuses and they were fine.

Comment: I mean, do you know the reason why that fuse blown. I didn't mean to ask whether you know recognize blown fuse.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you look at the Amazon article ([T800mAL2150V)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B009ETGLSS), you see it's a 800 mA, 250V, slow blow fuse.

I think you can buy themk also in the UK, if they don't have 800 mA, buy something close.

Btw, AliExpress sure ships to the UK, there are plenty to be bought, 10 pcs for 10 euro, or 25 euro for 200, enough for its entire lifetime.

Answer (score 2):

These are most likely 5×20mm glass tube fuses adhering to DIN 41660. Sometimes also called *G* (for glass) fuses. The T gives the hint – it's *träge*, German for *slow blow*.

These fuses should be available in any rating through any European electronics or even household electric parts supplier at a price of roughly 1€ per 10 pieces.